# Getting the difference between tuples in a list Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to get the difference between two tuples in a list formatted as List[(Int, Int)].

Example of list - `List[(3, 6), (4, 8), (2, 9)]`

I am able to get the sum of all the values with no issue, but having problems trying to get the difference between the (a, b) values. How can I return a list that matches `List[3, 4, 7]`?

Comment: `List((3,6), (4,8), (2,9)).map(t => t._2 - t._1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val l = List((3, 6), (4, 8), (2, 9))

val result = l.map { case (a, b) => b - a }
```

Comment: Thank you! I was definitely making it complicated for myself